# How to sync cookies with android webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have been creating an app which consist of a lo-gin page for a site. I am using HttpGet method and DefaultHttpClient for making connection. Everything works fine in with this. I will be receiving json response once the lo-gin is successful , in which i will be getting an URL to load with web-view. While loading the URL in web-view the cookies is not getting sync.I have been breaking my head for past one week. Can any one help me to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally after spending a 10 days i found a solution.

```
if (!Utils.cookies.isEmpty()){
                CookieSyncManager.createInstance(WebViewActivity.this);
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                for (Cookie cookie : Utils.cookies) {
                    Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;
                    String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + ";    domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
                    cookieManager.setCookie(sessionInfo.getDomain(), cookieString);
                    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                }
            }
```

this piece of code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For newer APIs , i.e API 21(Lollipop) and above, `CookieSyncManager` has been deprecated and `CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();` can be replaced by `CookieManager.getInstance().flush();` to write cookies to a persistent storage.