# Android user authentication in Android and webpages

Tags: php, android, authentication

Normally, when creating a website I create a loginform and when successfully logged in, a sessionvariable is set.
So I can check with this value if a page can be displayed: if isset session .... echo content ....

Now, I'm creating an Android app which has to combine both Android authentication and website authentication.
Some parts of the app will be loaded in Android components, but editing profile info will be done in a webpage loaded in a webview.

When starting the app, I show a loginscreen, when pushing the login-button, a call to a .php page is made which validates the login and password from a mysql database and passed back
a json result to my app.
When positive, the next screen is shown.
If then, the user chooses "edit profile" in the menu, a webpage is loaded in the webview.

But I'm stuck on how to authenticate the user in the webview pages.
How can I let the webview source page (for example let's say profile.php) know the user is logged in correctly.

I have found a lot of info, but none on how to pass the user to the webview page and validate it correctly.

So I want to know which is the right way to pass my user to my webview pages?
What do I have to pass in my Android code and how can I handle this in my php code?

I know about syncing cookies, but I don't really get the complete workaround:
[How to sync cookies with android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827639/how-to-sync-cookies-with-android-webview)

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Website scripts ( especially server side ones ) react the same way on PC or Mobile...

Comment: Offcourse, the problem is. The problem is that I have to know the user in the app and in webpages loaded in a webview.
When I logged in with a app level form, the user isn't known in my webpages so I have to pass the user some way secure.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the way of extending the `profile.php` page letting it accept `username` and `password` from the `POST`. This way You could post user credentials from within an Android application to Your `profile.php` page that will authenticate the user and return the profile page for that user. After editing and submitting the data again send user's credentials needed for authentification to store the profile data for the right user. This way it will work more like a web service.

I suggest always creating at least some simple web API or web service for mobile application to operate above the data rather than working with or operating above the concrete web page.

Comment: I get your point, but isn't that overkill to everytime pass the user credentials to a requested webpage in my webview?

Comment: Why would that be an overkill? It is the very same case as if anybody want's to log in at Your webpage. And it eliminates possible Cookie injection attack - let's assume I will listen a network and catch up Your cookies. Then I can send them to Your webpage and voilá, I'm logged in as somebody else (unless You are using HTTPS)... Anyway, the best solution is to forget about the webview and do the profile page as a form within android app itself...

Comment: what exactly do you mean with cookie injection attack in this case? Because where would I set a cookie?